# Html element disappearing in production

Tags: javascript, html, analytics

I'm working on an website where we insert a piece of html into the page when a user signs up e.g.

```
<span data-log-in-status="complete-sign-up" data-log-in-type="email" id="log_in_status" style="display:none;"></span>
```

We then have a page load event which finds this element, and pushes this info to Google analytics. In development I can see this element in the page source, in production however, this element is no-where to be found...

This being said however - the analytics complete-sign-up event is fired in both environments!

I'd really like to understand what's going on however - it's like the element appears in the page (the analytics event fires the correct data off) but then disappears... The only thing I can think of is if a piece of javascript somehow removes this element, or if the browser removes it.

Here's a screenshot of what's happening on the network:

[image]

Here's the javascript code which gets this data and pushes it to analytics:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var status, loginStatus;
    loginStatus = $('#log_in_status');

    if(loginStatus) {
        login_type = $(loginStatus[0]).attr('data-log-in-type');
        status = $(loginStatus[0]).attr('data-log-in-status');

        pushGAEvent(status, login_type, null, null);
        if(status === 'complete-sign-up') {
              goog_report_conversion(); //adwords
        }
    } 
});
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What code are you using to find the element and post to Google? You're going to have to post at least some of your javascript before anyone has a hope of answering this.

Comment: The code is working though - the strange thing is the html element disappearing. I'll post it anyway, but I don't see how it will help.

Comment: A little off topic but where you call .attr(...), you don't need the indexer call or the $ function call: `loginStatus.attr('data-log-in-type');`

Answer (score 0):

Your code will always fire, regardless of weather or not the element exists, as even empty jQuery objects evaluate to true.

Try:

```
if (loginStatus.length > 0)
```

instead of:

```
if (loginStatus)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out rjmunro, this is correct - I'll fix that. Still doesn't answer the original question though.

Comment: This probably explains why the analytics complete-sign-up event is fired in production even though the element is missing. So the problem is likely to be server side - the element is not being added on your production server.